# how to create web service in java web project and use is to give services to android app

Tags: java, web-services

Actually i am trying to give web services to android app. i have tried doing something like given below.

this is my Person.java entity.

```
    package com.avilyne.rest.model;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Person {

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Person() {

        id = -1;
        firstName = "";
        lastName = "";
        email = "";

    }

    public Person(long id, String firstName, String lastName, String email) {

        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }


    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;

}
```

This is my PersonResource.

```
package com.avilyne.rest.resource;

import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Request;

import com.avilyne.rest.model.Person;

@Path("/person")
public class PersonResource {

    private final static String FIRST_NAME = "firstName";
    private final static String LAST_NAME = "lastName";
    private final static String EMAIL = "email";

    private Person person = new Person(1, "Sample", "Person", "sample_person@jerseyrest.com");

    // The @Context annotation allows us to have certain contextual objects
    // injected into this class.
    // UriInfo object allows us to get URI information (no kidding).
    @Context
    UriInfo uriInfo;

    // Another "injected" object. This allows us to use the information that's
    // part of any incoming request.
    // We could, for example, get header information, or the requestor's address.
    @Context
    Request request;

    // Basic "is the service running" test
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String respondAsReady() {
        return "Demo service is ready!";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("sample")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Person getSamplePerson() {

        System.out.println("Returning sample person: " + person.getFirstName() + " " + person.getLastName());

        return person;
    }

    // Use data from the client source to create a new Person object, returned in JSON format.  
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Person postPerson(
            MultivaluedMap<String, String> personParams
            ) {

        String firstName = personParams.getFirst(FIRST_NAME);
        String lastName = personParams.getFirst(LAST_NAME);
        String email = personParams.getFirst(EMAIL);

        System.out.println("Storing posted " + firstName + " " + lastName + "  " + email);

        person.setFirstName(firstName);
        person.setLastName(lastName);
        person.setEmail(email);

        System.out.println("person info: " + person.getFirstName() + " " + person.getLastName() + " " + person.getEmail());

        return person;

    }
}
```

This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID"
    version="3.0">
  <display-name>JerseyRESTServer</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.avilyne.rest.resource</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

After running this code i am getting 404 (Link not found error.).
but when i used bellowed link for running this code then it is showing me content of index.jsp on browser..

http://localhost:8080/RestWebService/

But i want to access controller and i am not getting what to modify in link to access controller.
Picture shows file structure of my project.

[image: File Format]

And i want to access methods of PersonResource.java

Comment: Is that webapp mounted under `/JerseyRESTServer`? It looks like it may be the URL needs to be `http://localhost:8080/rest/person`.

Comment: i tried this http://localhost:8080/rest/person also. but still it is giving me 404 error

Comment: @kenney http://localhost:8080/RestWebService/ is giving me contents of inde.php. and i have updated my code now help me please

Comment: You might want to try adding all your jars into the WEB-INF/lib

Comment: I tried doing so. but files are not getting pasted in lib.

Comment: try 
http://localhost:8080/RestWebService/JerseyRESTServer/rest/person/sample

Comment: what error showing on browser

Comment: 404 error is showing

Comment: http://localhost:8080/JerseyRESTServer/rest/person/sample

or
http://localhost:8080/RestWebService/rest/person/sample

Comment: tried both not working. it is giving The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes error in console of eclipse

Comment: @gaurav this worked localhost:8080/RestWebService/rest/person/sample .